# Method that works with any List and Generics/Type Erasure aspects

Tags: java, list, generics, type-erasure, raw-types

First some code (Java 7) created just to illustrate my questions.

```
import java.util.*;

class Generics101 {



    public static void addTrue(List list) {
        list.add(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> testList = new ArrayList<>();

        addTrue(testList);
        System.out.println(testList.get(0));

        // testList.add(true);  // will not compile when uncommented

    }
}
```

I have the following two questions:

1. In `addTrue` method Eclipse hints that it does not like `raw types`.  When I try to change method parameters to use a wildcard `List<?> list` it won't compile. I looked through [Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) but could not find the answer. What am I missing here and where should I read about it?
2. The same [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) states that "*Generics were introduced to the Java language to provide tighter type checks at compile time...*"  I understand that due to `type erasure` such enforcement can't happen at run-time and so my above code compiles and runs.  It will trigger compiling error if the commented line is uncommented, so I assume that `tighter type checks` are in force within the same method. What is the exact scope for such enforcement? How is it formally defined?

Comment: `addTrue` _should_ only work for a `List<Boolean>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I try to change method parameters to use a wildcard List list it won't compile.

It wouldn't compile, because you can't add anything in a `List<?>`. Because you don't know which type of `List` is actually coming. For example, take your current case only. You are passing a `List<Integer>`. It would successfully be passed to `List<?>`. No issues. But you are adding `true`, a `boolean` type to it. If compiler allowed that, it would throw `ClassCastException` at runtime. So, it isn't allowed.

> so I assume that tighter type checks are in force within the same method. What is the exact scope for such enforcement?

No, it's not like that. It is not that the type checks are done under a certain scope. It's enforced wherever generics are used. Your current code won't compile if used with proper generics, because you are trying to add a `boolean` type to a `List<Integer>`. Why would you expect that to work?

Try changing your method to a generic method, and you'll see that it would fail to compile:

```
public static <T> void addTrue(List<T> list) {
    list.add(true);  // Won't compile
}
```

> I looked through Generics Tutorial but could not find the answer. What am I missing here and where should I read about it?

Well, that is the standard tutorial from Oracle. And that is where you should read. Apart from that, you can also go through a really nice collection of tutorial on generics at [Java Generics FAQs - Angelika Langer.](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What do you mean by "*if used with proper generics*"?

Comment: @PM77-1 Means using generics properly. Like if you make your method generic, then that code would fail to compile when you pass anything apart from `List<Boolean>`.

Comment: Re:  `<T> void`. I was under assumption that `<T>` represents the result type of the method and therefore incompatible with `void`.

Comment: @PM77-1 No, `<T>` represents type parameter for that method. You can go through the generics tutorial link towards the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I got that part now.

Comment: Also, its a very good practice to make a copy of the method parameter and make modifications on it and return the modified parameter. Agree that, one cannot enforce this rule every time, but always better whenever possible.